# Control Spring Cloud Task Launcher

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-task

I am launching tasks from cloud stream as this [state](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#stream-integration) . 
Is it possible to control how many simultaneous tasks can be run to make sure our system is not abused .

Comment: Hi,

I believe that kind of control is dependent on the underlying `TaskLauncher` environment that launches the tasks from Spring Cloud Stream. Please create a story [here][1] with some detail expressing your concerns. Thanks!


  [1]: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/issues

Comment: ill do that , i am using spring-cloud-deployer-local and i think [LocalTaskLauncher](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/blob/7a5449b12ed07ec2b54c2a517b5e1610d883ba33/spring-cloud-deployer-local/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/deployer/spi/local/LocalTaskLauncher.java)  is responsible for that but it doesn't have any queue option

Comment: yeah, we can track this from the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Issue has been closed https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/issues/275 forwarding me to spring data flow but I dont want to use local data flow as it is not for production

Comment: Spring Cloud Data Flow is the core project that contains the orchestration code for lauching tasks/deploying streams etc., It doesn't mean it only applies to `local` server. If you are concerned with `local` deployer, then it has to be https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local. But that is not recommended for production as well. There are other flavours CF, YARN, Kubernetes, Mesos deployers and Data Flow server versions are also available. Check here: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/ for more detail

Comment: I have the same requirement which I implemented modifying spring-cloud-task and spring-cloud-deployer-local repositories. I added a method 
 which gives number of currently running tasks and in LocalTaskLauncher wait processing new launch requests 
 if already runnin tasks is equals to max defined https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-local/issues/78